# URL issue in rails routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a link as below

```
<%= link_to member.full_name,{:controller => "reports",:action => "student_details", :stud_id => member.id,:vehicle_id=>@vehicle,:type=>@type,:month=>@start_date,:category=>@category } %>
```

In the routes.rb I have defined as

```
 map.connect    "/reports/student_details", :controller => reports',:action => 'student_details'
```

But when I click this link and go to the page, the url is showing as complete url with all the params appended in the link.. I want the url to be shortened like, `reports/student_details/id`
How do I do that.. Please help..

Comment: I think that of course shown like that since you're sending those params along to your destination, I still don't have any idea, but referring to Web post and get method is that was needed when we need to send any params? Unless you don't need those params. Hmm.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to modify the route to include the student id

```
map.connect "/reports/student_details/:stud_id", :controller => reports',:action => 'student_details'
```